# Firebase Realtime database read not working (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using realtime database in order to transfer information from a Windows computer to an Android phone. I am able to write data from the Windows PC to the database, but for some reason I am not able to read it off of the database to the Android. I am using Android studio Java. Here is the code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("users");
    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.getKey();
                PCs.add(new PC(name));
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < PCs.size(); i++) {
                PCs.get(i).setIp(dataSnapshot.child(PCs.get(i).getName()).child("ip").getValue(String.class));
                PCs.get(i).setConnected(dataSnapshot.child(PCs.get(i).getName()).child("status").getValue(Boolean.class));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

It just doesn't go into the onDataChange method, but also doesn't go to the onCancelled method.

Comment: Can you share your `json` database?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Not sure how to do that. It is basically users, then a PC name and then some info about it. users is the first child and has more children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it goes into neither of the callbacks, you may not have configured the connection to the database correctly. An easy way to fix that is to pass the database URL in the code, rather than depending on the `google-services.json` file:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("your database URL").getReference();
```

---

In general, you should *never* ignore possible errors, and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should look like:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException();
}
```

Comment: Still not working for some reason. The problem is with reading the data because I am able to use the authentication feature and it works great but I can't get the information out of the database.

Comment: "still not working" is hard to help with.  I recommend setting breakpoints in both callbacks and (again) running the code in a debugger. --- I also added an implementation of `onCancelled` to my answer, as leaving that empty is just ignoring potential problems.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. In the meantime I found a way to use the firestore database for the same job.